# Question timestamps are frequently wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, timestamps

According to the Android app, these are the five most recently active questions on RPG.SE:

[image: all the timestamps are those of the questions themselves]

(Here they are: [1](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33435/1204) [2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33413/1204) [3](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/25937/1204) [4](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33426/1204) [5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33388/1204))

The time stamps on all of these, though, are wrong. These have all been active in the last seven hours. Take a look at the full site:

[image: the time stamps are ok on the full site]

Scrolling down a little, some of the other questions are... better.

[image: some of these are ok]

([6](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33482/1204) [7](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/30189/1204) [8](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33474/1204) [9](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33480/1204))

I've noticed this pattern but I'm not 100% sure it's absolutely the cause:

- In most of these cases, the most recent activity was an edit.
- Most of the incorrect timestamps are the timestamps of the questions themselves. The exception is in question #5 above, where the most recent activity was an edit *on the question*, and the timestamp is the most recent answer.

Is the Android app ignoring edits in its timestamps?

Comment: The application is currently only using the creation date of a question for that field rather than also using the edit date and those of answers, great catch! This will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 5):

As of version 1.0.9 the application correctly uses the last modified date of questions for showing the timestamp in all lists rather than the creation date, thank you!